# Observables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to use an Observable to watch updates of a specific variable inside of another class. The class A, which will be the observed part, looks like this:

```
currentSheetNumber = 0;

public updateSheetNumber(): any {
  const measurementDataObservable = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.currentSheetNumber);
  });
  return measurementDataObservable;
}
```

The code of Class B, which wants to watch the changes, looks like this:

```
sheetNumberObserver;
sheetNumber: number = 0;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.sheetNumberObserver = this.measurementDataService.updateSheetNumber();
  this.sheetNumberObserver.subscribe((sheets) => {
    this.sheetNumber = sheets;
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, when I am changing the value `currentSheetNumber` in class A, the value `sheetNumber` of Class B doesn't change.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: `updateSheetNumber` creates a *new* observable every time, that doesn't seem right. Any subscriber would only ever get one value. You probably want to expose an observable based on a *subject* in A, see e.g. https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html where I show how to use this pattern.

Comment: the line you are pointing out is not relevant for my code, it was just written for test porposes. I deleted it from this question.

Comment: I'm talking about `measurementDataObservable = new Observable`

Comment: which angular version are  you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 9

Comment: @jonrsharpe what would be the alternative / correct way to declare the Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe points out, as things currently stand, your observable only ever emits a single value. It sounds like what you want is a way to notify subscribers whenever `currentSheetNumber` changes. Here's one possibility, in two steps. First, following @jonrsharpe's advice, let's instead expose a [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) (which is a special kind of observable) from your service:

```
public currentSheetNumber$ = new Subject();
```

Then, in class B:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.sheetNumberObserver = this.measurementDataService.currentSheetNumber$.subscribe((sheets) => {
    this.sheetNumber = sheets;
  });
}
```

At this point, whenever a value is "nexted" onto the `currentSheetNumber$` subject, `this.sheetNumber` (in class B) will be updated accordingly.

However, at the moment, the `currentSheetNumber$` subject is not tied in any way to your `currentSheetNumber` variable (in your service). That is, when you change `currentSheetNumber`, nothing happens to `currentSheetNumber$`. We need to "tie" these two together so that updates to `currentSheetNumber` are emitted by `currentSheetNumber$`.

One way to do this is be to add a special method for assigning `currentSheetNumber`, and *only* modify this variable using that method. Inside this method, we can both update `currentSheetNumber` *and* emit the new value to subscribers of our subject:

```
setCurrentSheetNumber(value: number) {
  // Update the value of `currentSheetNumber`...
  this.currentSheetNumber = value;
  // ...and send the new value to subscribers of `currentSheetNumber$`
  this.currentSheetNumber$.emit(value);
}
```

What this requires is that you replace any assignments to `currentSheetNumber` with calls to `setCurrentSheetNumber`.

This should work, but it involves following a discipline that we can't enforce (not making "direct" assignments to a variable). This is a potential source of difficult-to-diagnose errors.

Fortunately, there is a way to slightly tweak the current setup to provide a much more fool-proof experience. We can replace the `currentSheetNumber` variable with a pair of "[getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)/[setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)" methods. This will allow us to add our extra "nexting" logic whenever we assign to `currentSheetNumber` without having to worry about calling a separate method:

```
get currentSheetNumber(): value {
  // What goes here?
}

set currentSheetNumber(value: number) {
  this.currentSheetNumber$.next(value);
}
```

Now, whenever an assignment like `this.currentSheetNumber = 42` is made, the new value (in this case `42`) will be emitted to all subscribers of `currentSheetNumber$`. We're almost there.

The last problem we need to tackle is this: now that we've replaced `currentSheetNumber` with a getter/setter pair, where do we actually *store* the value? We've got several options. One is to add yet another variable, say `_currentSheetNumber`, which we use to maintain the current value, but we *never interact with directly*. That would look like this:

```
_currentSheetNumber = 0;

get currentSheetNumber(): number {
  return this._currentSheetNumber;
}

set currentSheetNumber(value: number) {
  this._currentSheetNumber = value;
  this.currentSheetNumber$.next(value);
}
```

Not only does this add an additional variable that we now need to think about, we are back to having to abide by a similar assignment discipline as before: we need to *never* assign to `_currentSheetNumber` directly. There has to be a better way.

There is. All we need to do is use a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) instead of a mere `Subject`. A `BehaviorSubject` is like a subject, but it "remembers" its current value, which is accessible via its `getValue` method. Here's what that looks like:

```
public currentSheetNumber$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

get currentSheetNumber(): number {
  return this.currentSheetNumber$.getValue();
}

set currentSheetNumber(value: number) {
  this.currentSheetNumber$.emit(value);
}
```

That oughta do it, but there's one BIG caveat that can be a source of errors and much frustration. A `BehaviorSubject` emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to. This might not be what you want in many cases, and it might force you to add some kludges (like skipping the first emitting value in subscriptions, etc.). In this case, you might be better off using the `_currentSheetNumber` strategy, despite its warts.

(Alternatively, you might be able to interact *directly* with the `currentSheetNumber$` behavior subject and avoid this racket, *or* write a custom subject that maintains its current state but doesn't emit it to new subscribers)

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. It definitely helped me with my problem. :)

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help!